# Suddenly ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable?

Tags: python, django, pythonpath

Suddenly my Django project showed me the following ImportError: **"ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?"**.

It ran fine before.

I work on Mac m1 using PyCharm Professional.

My Django is installed. My venv is activated. So, I guess I have problem with PYTHONPATH .

My interpreter is exactly I would like to use:
[image: My interpreter]

Actually I have some versions of Python. `which Python` shows me:

```
(venv) user_name@computer_name project_name % which python
python: aliased to /usr/bin/python3
(venv) user_name@computer_name project_name % which python3
/Users/user_name/PyCharmProjects/TrainingProjects/project_name/venv/bin/python3
(venv) user_name@computer_name project_name % which python3.9
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3.9
```

`python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` shows me:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python310.zip
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload
/Users/user_name/PyCharmProjects/TrainingProjects/project_name/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages
```

If I understand this output correctly, it means that there is no python 3.9 in my PYTHONPATH for now.

In my settings.py, there are:

```
import os
import sys #not active
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

```
which $PYTHONPATH
```

brings me `PYTHONPATH not found`.

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

brings me nothing.

The export:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
```

didn't help.

Comment: Hmmm.  Why would you want to have Python 3.9 in your path, if you are also showing Python 3.10?  Pick one.  Or the other.

Comment: Because `which python3` tells you that a venv is active (because `venv` is in the path, and it's within your project folder), and the `sys.path` result from the `python3` test shows `3.10` in the path, we can conclude that the venv is based off of the main 3.10 install. So of course if Django was installed in the main 3.9 install, it won't be seen. What exactly were the steps you took to install Django?

Comment: There are other diagnostics you can try. For example, if you try `python3 -m pip list`, do you see Django in the installed package list? How about if you use `python3.9`, or `python3.10`?

Comment: @JLPeyret yes, it is good question. When I try to set the PyCharm interpreter at Python3.10, I get: "Cannot set a python SDK to python 3.10... The SDK seems invalid".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel (1) I installed Django as usual, pip install django, to the (venv) project_folder,  (2) then I deleted, because of some side reasons, my venv folder from the project (3) then I reset venv again, (4) then I checked if Django is installed. Now I have: pip install django
Requirement already satisfied: django in ./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (4.0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in ./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from django) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.4.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from django) (3.5.2)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Using python3 -m pip list, I found Django 4.1.2. Sorry, maybe I don't understand your question about "python3.9, or python3.10": it seems I can't reach my python3.9 at all.

Comment: If you delete and re-create the venv, then Django will not be installed in the new one. The new venv is demonstrably based off 3.9, while `pip install django` gives an error message that refers to a 3.10 installation. The conclusion is that **when you run `pip`**, the venv is **not active**; but **when you run the code, it is**. Solution: since you want the venv to be active to run the code anyway, and the problem is that the venv does not contain Django, activate the venv *at the command line, and then* use `pip` to install it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I dunno if writing an answer is a good approach, but I may have some suggestions and I need a clean slate to write it in.  So...

First, let's forget about Python 3.9 and Python 3.10 and PYTHONPATH for a sec.

Second, let's try to find where django is installed.  This looks for a bin that django uses/delivers.

`mdfind -name django-admin.py`

which returned

```
/Users/me/kds2/issues2/500.macos/010.fixed.p1.bin_old_py/obsolete/opt.python@3.8/django-admin.py
/Users/me/kds2/venvs/bme/bin/django-admin.py 1️⃣
/Users/me/kds2/venvs/bme/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py 2️⃣
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py
```

I know my own environment, so I know what's interesting are the 2 under `/venvs/bme`.

In fact, I know 1️⃣, in `/bin/` basically loads 2️⃣ in `/site-packages/`

Your django will be structured the same way, just in another location.

From your posting so far, I assume your own venv is at

`/Users/user_name/PyCharmProjects/TrainingProjects/project_name/venv`

So, cd to its bin (which is also probably where you ran `source activate`)

`cd /Users/user_name/PyCharmProjects/TrainingProjects/project_name/venv/bin`

type the following command

`ls -l`

This is what it gets me (after I trim off some files from the output):

```
-rw-r--r--   1 me  staff  1991  8 Jan  2022 activate
-rw-r--r--   1 me  staff   917  8 Jan  2022 activate.csh
-rw-r--r--   1 me  staff  2059  8 Jan  2022 activate.fish
-rwxr-xr-x   1 me  staff   242 24 Jun 14:04 pip
-rwxr-xr-x   1 me  staff   242 24 Jun 14:04 pip3
-rwxr-xr-x   1 me  staff   242 24 Jun 14:04 pip3.10
lrwxr-xr-x   1 me  staff    21  8 Jan  2022python -> /opt/local/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x   1 me  staff     6  8 Jan  2022 python3 -> python
lrwxr-xr-x   1 me  staff     6  8 Jan  2022python3.10 -> python
```

OK, the important this is that these are symlinks pointing to the actual Python that is driving/hosting this venv.  My `python` is pointing to `/opt/local/bin/python` because I installed via macports but yours ought to be pointing to homebrews.

Maybe `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10` ?

And my venv is using Python3.10, as you can see.  I expect yours will be as, rather than 3.9.

OK, now let's see what that venv has set up as its environment?

`./python3 -m site` [doc about command](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#command-line-interface)

Notice the leading dot.  What this does is ignore PATH and whatever and just run this local python3.

What it outputs for me is a whole of useful information, about *this* virtualenv.

```
sys.path = [
    '/Users/me/kds2/venvs/bme/bin',
    '/Users/me/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages/_pdbpp_path_hack',
    '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python310.zip',
    '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10',
    '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
    '/Users/me/kds2/venvs/bme/lib/python3.10/site-packages', 
    '/Users/me/kds2/mygithub/pynoorm',
    '/Users/me/kds2/mygithub/bmedev',
    '/Users/me/kds2/mygithub/pip_stripper',
    '/Users/me/kds2/py2',
    '/Users/me/kds2/mygithub/lazy-regression-tests/lazy_regression_tests',
    '/Users/me/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages',
    '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/Users/me/Library/Python/3.10' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/Users/me/Library/Python/3.10/lib/python/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

That `sys.path` list above is location at which `import will try to find things.  Look for ones ending with` /site-packages`.

And for those, try to see if there is a django package.  Like this.

`ls -d /Users/me/kds2/venvs/bme/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django`

Sure enough, in the same location where I found my django-admin before.

```
/Users/jluc/kds2/venvs/bme/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django
```

Now, I don't know how pycharm and 3.9 figure into this, but that should give a little bit of an idea how your venv is put together.

Maybe you'd be better off reinstalling another venv with django and starting afresh.  Your code wouldn't affected.  Your call.

Comment: @JL Peyret **Thank you very much for so detailed answer, now I understand better where I have what.
The ./python3 -m site shows me place for** python3.9/site-packages, **but also**  USER_BASE: '/Users/gulnarakurmanova/Library/Python/3.9' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: '/Users/gulnarakurmanova/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
**How to have deal with it?**

Comment: I would create a new venv using 3.10, activate it, install Django, and then try running your code via `python manage.py runserver` on terminal.  If that works hook it up to pycharm (which I dont use).  A venv is separate from your code and not worth any great amount of time “fixing”.

Comment: Btw I was listening to a podcast that cautioned about using homebrew’s Python for dev.  Maybe that’s what happend here?  https://justinmayer.com/posts/homebrew-python-is-not-for-you/   No idea if that’s really a pbm or not.  I do use brew but only a little, but macport does the bulk of my installs, including Python’s.  Could also download the installer from python.org.  (Hey, y’all, not dissing brew, just mentioning what I’ve heard said by savvier folk.   Chime in if you know more about that).